# Exporting a function using Javascript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, date, undefined, clock

Just as a foreword; I started learning Javascript about 3 days ago and so my understanding of the requirements for some things aren't fully there.

So, I have a program I'm running that uses a clock to make folders, files and logs with a time stamp. But when I call the time from outside the function it just returns `undefined @ undefined:undefined:NaN`whereas within the function it returns the time like normal `10/2/2019 @ 11:6:45`

```js
function updateClock() {

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var day = currentdate.getDate();
    var month = currentdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentdate.getFullYear();
    this.date = " " + day + "/"
        + month + "/"
        + year;
    this.h = currentdate.getHours();
    this.m = currentdate.getMinutes();
    this.s = currentdate.getSeconds();
}

updateClock.prototype.run = function () {
    setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
};

updateClock.prototype.update = function () {
    this.updateTime(1);

    var time = " @ "
        + this.h + ":"
        + this.m + ":"
        + this.s;
    var datetime = this.date + time;
    console.log(datetime);
    return datetime;
};

updateClock.prototype.updateTime = function (secs) {
    this.s += secs;
    if (this.s >= 60) {
        this.m++;
        this.s = 0;
    };
    if (this.m >= 60) {
        this.h++;
        this.m = 0;
    };
    if (this.h >= 24) {
        this.day++;
        this.h = 0;
    }
};

var newclock = new updateClock();
newclock.run();




var timedate = updateClock.prototype.update();
console.log(timedate)
```

What do and how fix? Thanks I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `update` on instance of class not on `constructor`.

```js
function updateClock() {

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var day = currentdate.getDate();
    var month = currentdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentdate.getFullYear();
    this.date = " " + day + "/"
        + month + "/"
        + year;
    this.h = currentdate.getHours();
    this.m = currentdate.getMinutes();
    this.s = currentdate.getSeconds();
}

updateClock.prototype.run = function () {
    setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
};

updateClock.prototype.update = function () {
    this.updateTime(1);

    var time = " @ "
        + this.h + ":"
        + this.m + ":"
        + this.s;
    var datetime = this.date + time;
    console.log(datetime);
    return datetime;
};

updateClock.prototype.updateTime = function (secs) {
    this.s += secs;
    if (this.s >= 60) {
        this.m++;
        this.s = 0;
    };
    if (this.m >= 60) {
        this.h++;
        this.m = 0;
    };
    if (this.h >= 24) {
        this.day++;
        this.h = 0;
    }
};

var newclock = new updateClock();
newclock.run();




var timedate = newclock.update();
console.log(timedate)
```

Comment: Oooh, I thought of trying that but didn't know how to go about it, thanks very much!

Comment: @KnightPezz Accept the answer if its satisfactory.

Comment: The OP is calling *update* on the constructor's prototype, not the constructor.

Comment: @RobG True, it's just semantics as neither of them worked regardless. Whether calling the actual constructor or the prototype of it. Thank you for the clarification though.